# composer extends class not found

Tags: php, php-autoload

Como usar o extends com o autoloade do composer?
Da forma que está me retorna o seguinte error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'App\Modulos\Mail\Mail' not found in ...Google.php on line 7
```

**Composer**:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-4": {
        "App\\": "app/"
    }
}
```

**Estrutura**:

```
- Public
    app/
        Modulos/
                Mail/
                     Google.php
                     Mail.php
    vendor/
    bootstrap.php
    cli-config.php
    composer.json
    composer.lock
    index.php
    router.php
```

Public/**index.php**

```
<?php
require __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$google = new \App\Modulos\Mail\Google;

var_dump($google);
```

app/Modulos/Mail/**Google.php**

```
<?php

namespace Google;

use \App\Modulos\Mail\Mail;

class Google extends Mail {

}
```

app/Modulos/Mail/**Mail.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mail;

abstract class Mail {

}
```

Comment: no titulo @rray?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consegui resolver mudando apenas os "**namespace**" nos arquivos:

app/Modulos/Mail/**Google.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modulos\Mail;

use \App\Modulos\Mail\Mail;

class Google extends Mail {

}
```

app/Modulos/Mail/**Mail.php**

```
<?php

namespace App\Modulos\Mail;

abstract class Mail {

}
```